# Levitation height from electromagnet given holding force

Tags: electromagnetism

I am looking at purchasing an electromagnet described as "25 Kg Holding Force ELE-P40/20 model is $7.25/pc, sucked=250N"

If I have a small neodymium magnet. E.g [1]

How high would the electromagnet be able to levitate the small magnet, assuming it can't slip off the side.

A formula for height in terms of weight and magnetic strength would also be very helpful

Thank you

[1]https://magnet.com.au/neodymium-block-6-35mm-x-6-35mm-x-2-5mm.html?gclid=Cj0KCQiAvqDiBRDAARIsADWh5TcOytgpo0XsSqxUnUssLiE81aF3IJXV1I8jsDs47N7DdL85_LZu4QoaAu5ZEALw_wcB

Answer (score -1):

First, and most importantly, DO NOT LET THESE MAGNETS GET ANYWHERE NEAR EACH OTHER!

Forget about the levitating magnet sliding off the side. What will happen is that the neodymium magnet will immediately flip over and attract to the electromagnet with an incredibly violent force. This will either crush your hand if you are using it to position the neodymium magnet, or the impact of the magnet and electromagnet will create high velocity shrapnel that will injure anyone nearby.

Seriously, I've seen two of these neodymium magnets attract each other and slam together when they were placed on opposite ends of a work bench more than 150 cm apart. With these magnets, you will be putting a force that can lift kilograms on a projectile weighing grams.

The "25 kg holding force" probably refers to the mass of iron that the electromagnet can lift, not to any magnet-to-magnet force. The actual force between two magnets depends on the detailed designs of each. It's impossible to say without complex field simulators.

Comment: Thank you for your warning, but this is not helpful as an answer. Sorry for not being clear enough, when I said "sliding off the side" I meant imagine holding it in place, or for example a ring magnet on a pole that is capped at the top making it impossible to fly off.